# How to properly pass in parameters attached to an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, object, canvas

I am trying to call a function `grid.revive()` which is found in another file of my project but am having trouble figuring out how exactly to pass the parameters in it. 
My project consists of a grid drawn on an HTML canvas.
In `Grid.ts` (because our ts is being compiled down to js) I have functions kill and revive as follows:

```
    public kill( cell: Cell ) {
        this._cells.splice(this._cells.indexOf(cell));
    }

    public revive( cell: Cell ) {
        this.cells.push(cell);
    }
```

`Cell` is defined in `Cell.ts` as:

```
    export class Cell {
        x: number;
        y: number;`

        //noinspection JSUnusedLocalSymbols
        private constructor( x: number, y: number ) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    static fromKey( key: string ): Cell {
        let cellXY: string[] = key.split(":");
        return Cell.ofStr(cellXY[0], cellXY[1]);
   }


    static ofStr( x: string, y: string ) {
        return new Cell(parseInt(x), parseInt(y));
    }


    static of( x: number, y: number ) {
        return new Cell(x, y);
    }


    public asKey(): string {
        return `${this.x}:${this.y}`;
    };
    }
```

My question is how can I call grid.revive(cell_xcoordinate, cell_ycoordinate)? Should I be passing two values or just one since in other files the only argument is `cell`? What should the syntax of this look like? 
Where both x and y are accommodated for.

Comment: `revive(Cell.ofStr(x, y))`